# How do I use files that I dropped into Xcode in a Mac OS X Cocoa App when running the application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, resources

I'm creating a Cocoa Mac OS X app to install printers using a NSTask and the *lpadmin* command. I want to be able to use the .ppd files that are bundled with my application, e.g.

```
lpadmin -p name -E -v lpd://printer-location.com/public hp-laserjet-9050.ppd -L place
```

How can I do this where the (.ppd) file is located in my application bundle? Should I just write the file to the current directory, install, and then delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `File.ppd` to the "Supporting Files" folder (Xcode 4 screenshot):

[image: Xcode File Manager]

Run `lpadmin` through `NSTask` using the following file path:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"ppd" inDirectory:nil];
```

Comment: how can i do it in swift?